# WCF service freezed when created after new Control created

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I have a following sample project:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IFoo
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetText();
    }

    public class Foo : IFoo
    {
        public string GetText()
        {
            return "foo";
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Foo), new Uri("http://localhost:9995/foo")))
            {
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IFoo), new BasicHttpBinding(), "");

                //new Control();
                host.Open();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which works OK, by when I uncomment line `new Control()` and run the application again, the service stops to work.

Does someone know why it is happening? Why creating a new Control before calling `host.Open()`, stops the WCF service from working?

Note: I found out this problem after debugging a big project where some services weren't working. It appeared that the services with which there is a problem were created only after some `UserControl` has been created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you opened `ServiceHost` instance before starting the UI thread, it will run on its own thread. Otherwise it will use the message loop (UI thread).

In your case, when a new Control is created before host is opened, wcf will use message loop. At the same time this: `Console.ReadKey()` blocks main thread, so your app hangs.

If you will write like this:

```
//Console.ReadKey();
while (true)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

It will work. Try it.

For more detail infomation see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163321.aspx) and some SO answers:
[WCF threading - non-responsive UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949477/wcf-threading-non-responsive-ui)

And one more great book [link](http://books.google.ru/books?id=-AUyj6S7etwC&pg=PA244&lpg=PA244&dq=wcf%20message%20loop&source=bl&ots=4wft_-tLJP&sig=qiKrGFhcmnD55WLIIt9L2Iv1qB4&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=WDG4Uu7zNqGF4ASKyoDQCg&ved=0CGoQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=wcf%20message%20loop&f=false) with exactly (I think so) your problem.

**EDIT**:

When `host.Open()` is called WCF is checking value of `SynchronizationContext.Current` (see [SynchronisationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163321.aspx)). If it is `null` then WCF will use new context, if it is not null WCF will use existing context.

Before you call `new Control()` `SynchronizationContext.Current` was `null`, after it was called `SynchronizationContext.Current = WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`. This means main thread and a message loop is used, but `Console.ReadKey()` blocks the main thread. So app hangs.

Another solution is to write like this:

```
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IFoo), new BasicHttpBinding(), "");

// this will force WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext to be created
new Control();

// create new sync context, and WCF will use it, not WinForms context
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());

host.Open(); // WCF will respond
Console.ReadKey(); // main thread is blocked
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! It works, both in the sample project I pasted in the question, and in the target project which I was debugging.

Comment: You are welcome! I reminded one more solution, maybe you will like it more.