# How to Update Windows Application GUI through WCF hosted in Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, wcf, windows-services

I am trying to build a system in which a desktop application is running on my server machine and WCF service is hosted as Windows Service on the same system.
WCF have below Service Contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface Communication
{
        [OperationContract]
        void GetStatus(string message);
}
```

This Method is called by multiple clients. Clients sends a string as parameter to server.
My query is, whenever client calls this method of service, this message should be displayed on the Windows application GUI running on server.

How to achieve this. I do not want to do polling. Any other method? 
I have searched net for the same, but I am confused now.

Comment: Make your Service UI app to host its own local service, that way the windows service can just query your service and the UI will respond accordingly

Comment: Make sure that [ServiceBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext=false)], this will cause calls to your service to be processed on their own thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949477/wcf-threading-non-responsive-ui